# Google Cloud VM Autoscaling in Terraform - Updating Images

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I can create a fully-functioning autoscaling group in GCP Compute via Terraform, but it's not clear to me how to update the ASG to use a new image.

Here's an example of a working ASG:

```
resource "google_compute_region_autoscaler" "default" {
  name    = "example-autoscaler"
  region  = "us-west1"
  project = "my-project
  target  = google_compute_region_instance_group_manager.default.id

  autoscaling_policy {
    max_replicas    = 10
    min_replicas    = 3
    cooldown_period = 60
    cpu_utilization {
      target = 0.5
    }
  }
}

resource "google_compute_region_instance_group_manager" "default" {
  name   = "example-igm"
  region = "us-west1"

  version {
    instance_template  = google_compute_instance_template.default.id
    name               = "primary"
  }

  target_pools       = [google_compute_target_pool.default.id]
  base_instance_name = "example"
}

resource "google_compute_target_pool" "default" {
  name = "example-pool"
}

resource "google_compute_instance_template" "default" {
  name           = "example-template"
  machine_type   = "e2-medium"
  can_ip_forward = false
  tags           = ["my-tag"]
  disk {
     source_image = data.google_compute_image.default.id
  }
  network_interface {
    subnetwork = "my-subnet"
  }
}

data "google_compute_image" "default" {
  name = "my-image"
}
```

My goal is to be able to create a new Image (out of band) and then update my infrastructure to utilize it.  It doesn't appear possible to change a `google_compute_instance_template` while it's in use.

One option I can think of is to create two separate templates, and then adjust the `google_compute_region_instance_group_manager` to refer to a different `google_compute_instance_template` which references the new image.

Another possible option is to use the `version` block inside the instance group manager.  You can use this similarly to above to essentially toggle between two versions.  You start with one "version" at 100%, and the other at 0%.  When you create a new image, you update the version that is at 0% to point to the new image and change its skew to 100% and the other to 0%.  I'm not actually sure this works, because you'd still have to update the template of the version that's at 0% and it might actually be in use.

Regardless, both of those methods are incredibly bulky for a large-scale production environment where we have multiple autoscaling groups in multiple regions and update them frequently.

Ideally I'd be able to change a variable that represents the image, `terraform apply` and that's it.  Is there any way to do what I'm describing?

Comment: I'm talking from AWS experience, but: the autoscaling groups keep running the old version of template until new ones are boot up and/or the old ones are decommissioned.

Comment: @MarkoE yes that is generally correct, though in GCP there are some options you have about how aggressive the ASG will replace instances.  That said, my question is agnostic to the process the ASG will undertake to replace the instances.  I'm just trying to figure out the best/easiest way to represent the change in code (however the ASG applies that change).

Comment: Could you use `lifecycle` option `create_before_destroy` maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `lifecycle` block with the `create_before_destroy` but also the attribute `name` of the `google_compute_instance_template` resource must be omitted or replaced by `name_prefix` attribute.

> With this setup Terraform generates a unique name for your Instance Template and can then update the Instance Group manager without conflict before destroying the previous Instance Template.

References:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance_template#using-with-instance-group-manager

Comment: Yes, can't believe I missed that.  Thank you.